# Grant rights to update procedures to a redshift user

Tags: amazon-redshift, psql

I want to create a user that can only update stored procedures in redshift. The procedures are given as .sql files that start like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema_name.procedure_name
...
```

Hence I created the new user in psql and tried to assign the rights: `GRANT CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE to ci`.

But when I try to update with the new user `psql -h $host -U ci -d $database -p $port -f file.sql` it fails with  `ERROR:  permission denied for schema schema_name`. (This works with the admin user)

Comment: That is impossible in PostgreSQL (only the owner and a superuser can `ALTER` a function). No idea about Redshift.

Comment: Ok, that's a start. Does it mean if I would delete the function an recreate it with my ci user it should be able to alter it?

Comment: You just use the same user to create the function originally and later to `ALTER` it. That will always work, unless somebody messed with the schema permissions in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synthezising from the different comments and answers:

1. The `ci` user must be owner of the function. This means the function must be deleted beforehand (and recreated by `ci` afterwards)
2. `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_name TO ci` is necessary but not sufficient.
3. I was finally able to make it work after additionally adding `GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA schema_name TO ci;`

Open questions:

- There should be a more minimal set of rights to accomplish this.
- Do the necessary privileges depend on the sql statements in the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about splitting the CREATE and REPLACE permissions, but the error you're getting seems unrelated. I think your user `ci` also needs USAGE permission on the schema.

```sql
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_name TO ci
```